# Formatting datetime xlabels in matplotlib (pandas df.plot() method)

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I can't figure out how to change the format of these x-labels. Ideally, I'd like to call `strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` on them.  I've tried things like `set_major_formatter` but was unsuccessful.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
date_range = pd.date_range('2014-01-01', '2015-01-01', freq='MS')
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': np.random.randint(0, 10, len(date_range))}, index=date_range)
ax = df.plot(kind='bar')
```

[image: ugly x label formats]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The objects in the `date_range` DF are `Timestamp` objects. Call `Timestamp.strftime` on each object:

```
date_range = pd.date_range('2014-01-01', '2015-01-01', freq='MS')
date_range = date_range.map(lambda t: t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
print date_range
array([2014-01-01, 2014-02-01, 2014-03-01, 2014-04-01, 2014-05-01,
       2014-06-01, 2014-07-01, 2014-08-01, 2014-09-01, 2014-10-01,
       2014-11-01, 2014-12-01, 2015-01-01], dtype=object)
```

This allows for more general formatting options versus truncating the ticklabel string.

Comment: Thanks! Accepted yours because it let me call strftime and thus allows for more formatting options, as you pointed out

Answer (score 12):

Simply access the tick labels and change them:

```
xtl=[item.get_text()[:10] for item in ax.get_xticklabels()]
_=ax.set_xticklabels(xtl)
```

[image]

Comment: `_` being a [throwaway variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5893946/812102) here.

Answer (score 8):

You could just pass new labels exactly with your preferred strftime:

```
ax.set_xticklabels([pandas_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for pandas_datetime in df.index])
```

It's not the prettiest answer, but it gets the job done consistently.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution for me was:

```py
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter

date_form = DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_form)
```

Answer (score 1):

## This gets the job done but it is not ideal. RCCG's answer is perfect bc it does not change the datetime type of the index.

```
df.index=df.index.date
df.plot(kind='bar)
```